# Shared mailbox or user mailbox for creating an account with an online service?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, administrator

Question: Without using my own work email address, is it best practice to sign your company up for online services using a new email account OR a new shared mailbox email address? (email client is the Outlook desktop app)

Detail: At my company, I will be setting us up for the first time on an online services provider (let's call this provider 'CloudServices'). During setup, I will be creating a new administrator account, detached from my name.

Rather than use my own Outlook email address (ie. user01@company.co.uk), I want to create the root account on 'CloudServices' under a new admin email address (ie. cloud_admin@company.co.uk). I will then add myself (user01) and a couple of other staff (user02, user03 etc.) as admin members on the CloudServices website.

How should I create this new 'cloud_admin@company.co.uk'? Should this just be an Outlook 'shared inbox'? Or should it be a new 'user inbox'? I'm confused with the Outlook terminologies regarding account/inbox creation and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

What's the specific service that you are working with?

If you are working with Microsoft Azure and Exchange server, according to my experience, the obvious differences between shared mailbox and usermailbox are as follows, you could choose it for your need:

Normal usermailbox has creadential and need configure in Outlook with the username and password mannually.

A [shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/shared-mailboxes/shared-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019) is a type of user mailbox that doesn't have its own username and password, it would be mapped to the mailbox automatically in Outlook after you assign the permission for it and allow multiple users to monitor and reply to email sent to a general email address.

I'm not sure if there are any differences for amzon service, if it's your case, you could try to contact amazon support directly.

Comment: thanks, but I think I've confused things by mentioning Azure and AWS. If we forget those exact providers, I think a more generic questions is: 'Without using my own work email address, is it best practice to sign up for online services using a new Outlook email account OR a new shared mailbox email address?'. I've updated my question with this new clarification.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I think the choice may depend on your specific requirements for this "new address". For example, if you just need all members receive the messages sent to this address, you could use DL as Algeriassic mentioned. If you would like to manage calendars , it's recommended to create shared mailbox and assign the permission to members.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Distribution List (DL), which is a sort of a group where you add specific users to that DL (group).

The DL will have it's own email but no mailbox, username or password. All users part of this group (DL) will receive a copy of the email that is destined to that DL.

If a user leaves the company or is not part of the team anymore, you can remove him from the DL.

Hope this helps.